# Adobe Illustrator Saving to PSD: "Not enough memory to save the file"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

This is on CS5.5 under Windows XP Professional.

There seems to be a known issue about saving (large) Adobe Illustrator files to PSD ([thoroughly discussed](http://vectips.com/tips/export-illustrator-files-to-photoshop/)), where the exporter will complain about "Not enough memory to save the file". This happens regardless of the available memory on the computer, and seems to be a limitation in the PSD exporter itself.

The only possible solution so far seems to be to copy-n-paste each layer separately from the illustrator file and into the open Photoshop file. We need to keep the layers intact (and not merged), so selecting all the layers at the same time doesn't work.

Do anyone have a workaround to the actual, original export issue, or a way to be able to get the layer information into Photoshop without handling each layer separately?

Answer (score 4):

Unchecking **Anti-Alias** seems to work, unfortunately it gives unsatisfactory results in my opinion. You lose the crispness on the edges of artwork without anti-aliasing.

Comment: Yes, that works - but lacking anti-aliasing it is (as you note) completely unusable for any partical use. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. Go to: Edit > Preferences > Performance and change the amount of memory that is assigned to Photoshop by moving the slider to the right. Check also that you have enough space on your scratch disks.

Answer (score 1):

when exporting as psd from AI, after clicking save, "photoshop export options" dialog box opens. Make sure anti-alias box is UNCHECKED. That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Flip your picture on its side and try exporting it.  Worked for me - apparently there's a problem exporting files that are too wide, but too tall isn't a problem.  Sounds silly, but it was the only solution that worked for me. :)